# convert a string to a dict when literal_eval not working

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to convert a pandas column value from str to dict.

The value looks like this :

```
'""en-US":"!!PLAY""'
```

I tried with eval, with literal_eval, with json.loads and I only have errors SyntaxError or json.decoder.JSONDecodeError.

The only solution left I see is to find each string with regex and form a dict after. That is pretty heavy to do. Anyone with an idea ?

Comment: Well, that is not a valid Python expression or `dict` literal, therefore it cannot be evaluated as an expression via `eval()` or as a literal via `ast.literal_eval()`... It's also not valid JSON, so same thing. It's just a string... You have to parse it yourself, either via regex, or by removing the extraneous quotes and splitting on `":"`.

Comment: It's not that difficult to make a regex for this

Comment: @ddejohn It's a valid Python string (`s = '""en-US":"!!PLAY""'` works), but the content isn't a valid Python literal or JSON string.

Comment: Right, I meant not a valid Python dictionary either as an expression or as a literal.

Comment: Maybe you can shed some light on how did you get it into pandas DF, and do you control the input (i.e. I guess it maybe a problem elsewhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string at ":" then add them to dictionary use slicing to remove extra quotes

```py
key , val = '""en-US":"!!PLAY""'.split(":")
dic = {key[2:-1]:val[1:-2]}
print(dic)
```

Comment: thanks, it's the only solution!